# Facebook login for Meteor website only works if the url starts with www

Tags: facebook, url, meteor, facebook-login

So I have a website running at www.example.com. It has no SSL (yet). If I go to www.example.com/login it logs in smoothly. If I try the same thing from example.com/login, it opens the login window and nothing more happens. Why is that? Any hints whether its because of my fb settings? But I always put both options into the Valid Oauth field

Comment: Please check your redirect uri field in fb settings

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra yes, I checked it and I have both, the http://example.com and http://www.example.com in there. The facebook popup always shoes www.example.com . This is also my ROOT_URL in mup.js. Maybe I need to change something there? put the server IP?

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra yeah I just checked, if I change the mup ROOT_URL to example.com, the fb login works from example.com but not from www.example.com -.- Can I specify two ROOT_URL

Comment: use without www everywhere even in ROOT_URL

Comment: you cannot specify two ROOT_URL

Comment: but then, if the user types in www.example.com the login doesnt work. My workaround is, that I use with www. everywhere and if the user types example.com, it takes them to www.example.com

Comment: use nginx to redirect www to non www